# Group By in java 8 with multiple levels of grouping

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have such structure

```
| Director1 | Manager1 | Employee1 |
| Director1 | Manager1 | Employee2 |
| Director1 | Manager2 | Employee3 |
| Director2 | Manager3 | Employee4 |
```

I fetch this data from Db to Pojo like this

```
@Data
public class Workers {
 private String directorName;
 private String managerName;
 private String employeeName;
}
```

DB is denormalized.

Mow in java code I need to group this response to not to return redundant data. My response data looks like

```
@Data
public class WorkersResponse{
 private String directorName;
 ...
 private List<Manager> managers;
}

@Data
public class Manager{
 private String manager;
  ...
 private List<Employee> employee;
}

@Data
public class Employee{
 private String employee;
 ...
}
```

With grouping I want to receive List. For now I figured out how to group directors :

```
Map<WorkersResponse, List<Workers >> collect = all.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> {
                WorkersResponse workersResponse= new WorkersResponse();
                workersResponse.setDirector(v.getDirectorName());
                return workersResponse;
            }));
```

But how should then I populate list with Managers and Employees?

Comment: You only need names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the grouping requirement, you should try using nested grouping along with `Collectors.mapping` such as:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> groupingRequirement = workersList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Workers::getDirectorName,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Workers::getManagerName,
                        Collectors.mapping(Workers::getEmployeeName,
                                Collectors.toList()))));
```

Thereafter mapping to objects of the desired type is the only constraint left while you iterated over the entries of the collected `Map` -

```
List<WorkersResponse> workersResponses = groupingRequirement.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new WorkersResponse(e.getKey(), // director name
                e.getValue().entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(ie -> new Manager(ie.getKey(), // manager name
                                ie.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(Employee::new)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can create Employee when mapping also

Comment: @Eklavya True, now that I see another answer adapts to it, wouldn't make much sense to edit this answer further. Anyway, the approach of nested grouping is crucial to the solution.

Comment: @Naman maybe you can update it now. I have removed other one.

Comment: @Naman I added an answer, collect and mapping together like your solution, hope it's ok to you.

Comment: @Naman thanks a lot. I figured first part before you posted your answer, but second part helper me a lot. And yeah I've chained it as in second answer proposed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Naman already given the better answer, just want to add,
you can get `WorkersResponse` in this way also using `collectingAndThen`

```
List<WorkersResponse> requirement = workersList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Workers::getDirectorName,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Workers::getManagerName,
                        Collectors.mapping(w -> new Employee(w.getEmployeeName()),Collectors.toList())),
                    e -> e.entrySet().stream().map(ie -> new Manager(ie.getKey(), ie.getValue()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()))),
            e -> e.entrySet().stream().map(ie -> new WorkersResponse(ie.getKey(), ie.getValue()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```